# Hash functions which avoid collisions on a fixed set of inputs

Tags: hash, hashmap, hashtable

I have a space of size ~2<sup>38</sup> from which I sample a set of ~2<sup>28</sup> distinct objects (their distribution is structured but hard to characterize). I need a procedure for taking one such sample and constructing a function that converts each object into a 32-bit integer, such that there are much fewer collisions on this fixed sample relative to a hash function that is collision resistant on the whole space (e.g. FNV or CRC). Is there any class of functions that might achieve this behavior, i.e. they have many collisions on structured subset(s) of the domain, but are disperse elsewhere?

It seems the most common approach in this situation is to use an evolutionary / reinforcement learning algorithm that treats the inputs as a dataset and optimizes for the hash function. But for my application I would prefer to simply check a large set of candidate functions if there is a principled way of coming up with a promising family of such functions.

Comment: Possibly of interest:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function

Comment: Yes this is very helpful, thanks a lot!

Comment: There's a gnu tool for constructing perfect hashes: gperf. I don't know how it works on a key space this large. Also consider optimal binary search trees. They might be competitive for this problem.

Comment: "their distribution is structured but hard to characterize" - exploiting the patterns here is the only practical avenue of exploration for you, which such a huge number of keys.  To go from decent (FNV/CRC) and a load factor of 1 / 2^10 to a load factor of 1 / 16 and expect "much fewer" collisions is a hell of an ask.  While I can't help you with that without knowing the distribution structure, I'd just point out that for some computing purposes - like hash tables - collisions aren't as bad as you might think; modern implementations use SIMD to search a set of candidate buckets concurrently.